# Inserting MYSQL data to database table associated with fields from Drop Down menu

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu, menu

**Problem: I need to insert additional data into a database table that is associated with a record selected using a drop down menu.**

I am populating a drop down menu with Tennis players names from a MySQL table, called Player. The rows of the DB table contain 3 columns a unique ID, players surname and firstname. The drop down shows the surname and first name.

Currently a user can select a player and after pressing the submit button, its surname is correctly inserted into another DB table, the Staging table. **But I also need to insert the players ID and firstname, but I cannot get the correct ID and Firstname to also be inserted into the Staging table.**

I cannot seem to be able to find a way of associating other data with the user selection made from the drop down menu.

Can anyone from the community suggest a change to the code below that enables a players ID and firstname to be inserted into the staging table at the same time as the surname.

Any assistance the community can give would be much appreciated. The code is as follows:

```
<?php 
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","","Tennis") or die("Could not connect: ".mysql_error());

    if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {

        $surname=$_POST['winner'];

        $id = $_POST['ID'];
        $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];

        // Insert into database what the user selected.
        $qresult = mysqli_query($link,"insert into staging (ID,surname,firstname) values ('$id','$surname','$firstname')"); 

    } // end of the main submit condition.


?>
<h1>Tennis Tournament</H1>

    <?php 
    // Fetch player data to populate drop down menu.
    $selectSQL = "SELECT * FROM PLAYER ORDER BY SURNAME";
    $selectSQL = mysqli_query($link, $selectSQL );

    echo '<form method="post" action="Tennis2.php"><br>';

    // Drop down menu.
    echo '<select name="winner">';

        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($selectSQL,MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
            $id = $row['ID'];
            $firstname = $row['FIRSTNAME'];
            echo '<option value="'.$row['SURNAME'].'">'.$row['SURNAME'].' '.$row['FIRSTNAME'].'</option>';
        }
    echo '</select>';

    echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" />';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="ID" value="'.$id.'" />';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1" />';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="firstname" value="'.$firstname.'" />';
    echo '</form>';

    mysqli_free_result($selectSQL);

    ?>
```

Comment: Make sure you have the ID of the player in all your tables and use the ID as a selector to make the relation. In your dropdown, use the ID not the surname as the given value.

Comment: Doing this `echo '<input type="hidden" name="ID" value="'.$id.'" />';` outside the while loop, means you only ever capture the id from the last player in the loop. Put `$id` in the `value="' . $id . "'` of the `<option>` tag and then whatever palyer is selected you get the Id from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Page.php**

Pass `ID` in option values. No Need of hidden fields.

```
<?php 
// Fetch player data to populate drop down menu.
$selectSQL = "SELECT * FROM PLAYER ORDER BY SURNAME";
$selectSQL = mysqli_query($link, $selectSQL );

echo '<form method="post" action="Tennis2.php"><br>';

  // Drop down menu.
  echo '<select name="winner">';
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($selectSQL,MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
      echo '<option value="'.$row['ID'].'">'.$row['SURNAME'].' '.$row['FIRSTNAME'].'</option>';
    }
  echo '</select>';

  echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" />';
echo '</form>';

mysqli_free_result($selectSQL);

?>
```

**Tennis2.php**

Catch That `ID` passed from dropdown and fetch it's related data like surname, first name and insert into staging table.

```
<?php 
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","","Tennis") or die("Could not connect: ".mysql_error());

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

  $id_selected = $_POST['winner'];

  $selectSQLquery = "SELECT * FROM PLAYER WHERE ID = $id_selected LIMIT 0,1";
  $selectSQL = mysqli_query($link, $selectSQLquery );

  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($selectSQL,MYSQLI_BOTH);
  $surname = $row['SURNAME'];
  $firstname = $row['FIRSTNAME'];

  // Insert into database what the user selected.
  $qresult = mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO staging (ID,surname,firstname) values ('$id','$surname','$firstname')"); 

} // end of the main submit condition.
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This code

```
<?php 
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","","Tennis") or die("Could not connect: ".mysql_error());

        $ID=$_POST['winner'];

       if($ID){

        // Insert into database what the user selected.
        $qresult = mysqli_query($link,"insert into staging (select * from PLAYER where ID = $ID)"); 
  }

?>
<h1>Tennis Tournament</H1>

    <?php 
    // Fetch player data to populate drop down menu.
    $selectSQL = "SELECT * FROM PLAYER ORDER BY SURNAME";
    $selectSQL = mysqli_query($link, $selectSQL );

    echo '<form method="post" action="Tennis2.php"><br>';

    // Drop down menu.
    echo '<select name="winner">';

        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($selectSQL,MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
            $id = $row['ID'];
            $firstname = $row['FIRSTNAME'];
            echo '<option value="'.$row['ID'].'">'.$row['SURNAME'].' '.$row['FIRSTNAME'].'</option>';
        }
    echo '</select>';

    echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" />';
    echo '</form>';

    mysqli_free_result($selectSQL);

    ?>
```

Comment: While code snippets which solve the problem are welcome, code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged. Please add some explanation, why this solves the problem and what your change is.